# Adding ScrollView to RelativeLayout changes position of wigdets

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

The following is the XML of my layout. It explicitly states that the title, time and description TextViews should be under the image of the alarm. However, as the screen shot shows, the `TextView`s have moved into the `ImageView`. Why does this happen and how can I fix this? The problem only started happening when I added the scrollview.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_alarm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/alarm"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_layout_alarm"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_alarm_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_alarm"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img_alarm"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        />   
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_alarm_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_alarm"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/img_alarm"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        />  
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_alarm_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_alarm_title"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lbl_alarm_title"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lbl_alarm_time"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        />   

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_stop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_alarm_description"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip"
        android:paddingRight="20dip"
        android:text="@string/stop_layout_alarm"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Image**

[image]

Comment: in `ScrollView`try `android:fillViewport="true"`

Comment: That sorts out the positioning problem but the ScrollView doesn't scroll now.

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to have `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` inside an element which can be scrolled. What happens if you remove it?

Comment: @jush: The image goes off-centre and it doesn't look as good.

Comment: removing `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` make any effect on `Scroll` ?

Comment: Your `ScrollView` uses `match_parent` which means it will take as much space as the parent so why do you use a `ScrollView` at all? According to your xml you're not allowing it to grow more than the parent view. Your xml says that the `RelativeLayout` should `match_parent` so it won't grow larger than the `ScrollView`. Honestly, I would change those `match_parent` to `wrap_content` and use `gravity` to center the image horizontally and use margin top.

Comment: @W.K.S did you get a chance to try what I suggest above? Using `wrap_content`s, gravity and margin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cute app :)

hmm... not sure why it's doing it, looks like you have the right code, without busting out eclipse. but i've also had some weird bugs with relativelayout that i didn't understand and didn't have time to debug.

i do know of an alternative way you can accomplish what you're looking for -

have a scrollview that encases a linearlayout instead of a relative layout. Do these things:

1. For the linearlayout, you can set orientation = vertical so that it's still a top down  order.
2. For the part where you need two textviews where one is aligned to the right and the other is aligned to the right, you need another inner linearlayout with its orientation=horizontal. then have one element align parent left, and the other align parent right. add a weightSum=1 attribute to this linearlayout and have each of the two textviews layout_width=0.5 so that each is half the width of the screen
3. Apply a weightSum=1 attribute to your outer most linearlayout, and see each element inside so that it's layout_weight sum adds up to 1. layout_weight will allow an element to take up that much % of real estate on the screen. like if you set your imageView to have android:layout_weight=0.8 then it'll take up 80% of the screen... since mathematically, (layout_weight/weightSum) = (.08/1)  = 80%

try to use that mechanism instead, and if should work :) if it's confusing i can give code 
example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_alarm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:src="@drawable/alarm"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_layout_alarm"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_alarm_title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/empty"
                />   
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_alarm_time"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/empty"
                />  

        </LinearLayout>

          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_alarm_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:text="@string/empty"
            />   

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_stop"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="20dip"
            android:paddingRight="20dip"
            android:text="@string/stop_layout_alarm"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

i hope this deserves at least an upvote for the effort :D

Comment: wait a minute... while i was editing this i just noticed - all your textveiws and buttons have layout_width="wrap_content", change that to layout_width="match_parent" instead

Comment: Thanks. I was going for cute :)
I'd prefer to leave that as a last resort. I tried to use a LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout but I couldn't get the title TextView to align to the left of the ImageView and the time TextView to align to the right of the ImageView. 

I'll try the weight thing you suggested. Thanks :)

Comment: well done :) hmm... i added some sample code, but i didn't run it in eclipse so hopefully it should be okay. if not, tinker with the layout_weight, layout_width, and all that... using 0dp so android can autosize it

Comment: OK, I managed to get it to work but by using a `LinearLayout`-`TableLayout` combination. I used padding to get all the elements about in the centre. I used the `TableLayout` to get the title `TextView` and the time `TextView` on the same line. It looks how I wanted and scrolls. Thanks :)